# apt update docker.com Release 404 not found

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, updates

I recently try to install docker using this method

```
curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sh get-docker.sh
```

but it doesn't worked for me maybe broken packages or something after that I installed docker && docker compose using apt method and that's working good but when I try to update or upgrade my system I can see following messages I don't actually know what was the issue please give me a solution thanks.

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                  
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                         
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                  
Hit:7 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                         
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic InRelease                                    
Hit:10 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                
Err:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic Release                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.35.8.98 443]
Hit:13 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                              
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libxml2 libxml2:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How can I remove from my source list because I don't need it anymore

Comment: I can see /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.save  `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bionic stable`
@mchid

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [the docker page for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#x86_64_repo), the problem is that it should be `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu` instead of `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian`.

Run the following command to fix this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/debian/ubuntu/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt update
```

However, if that doesn't fix the issue, run the following command:

```
sudo sed -i 's|docker.com/linux/debian|docker.com/linux/ubuntu|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I have used the following in Linux Mint:

1. Determine the Ubuntu codename using the command below (and NOT the version codename):

   ```
   $ cat /etc/os-release | grep -i codename
   VERSION_CODENAME=una
   UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
   ```
2. Replace the Ubuntu codename in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`:

   ```
   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu <CODENAME> stable
   ```

   In my case the command on docker website has set the codename to **una** (docker determines it using `lsb_release -cs`), but I had to change it to **focal**.

Comment: Greetings. LM is not Ubuntu. It is off topic here.

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Parrot Os, You have to Change parrtos in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list** to the current debian release of your os version (bullseye, buster and so on).

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

The above command will open the docker.list file where you can change the link to now look like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
```

Just replace the bullseye with your debian codename and run sudo apt-get update again.